# Why is 0:0 ignored as an operator?

Tags: javascript, operators, calculator

I'm using this Drupal module that's called Webform Calculator, and it makes us of so-called operators.

There's one formula based on operators that *almost* does the job:

```
({total_weight}==0? 0:0) || ({total_weight}<=2? 5:0) || ({total_weight}<=10? 6:0) || ({total_weight}<=30? 10.5:0)
```

This is what it's doing right:

- If the total weight equals or is less than 2, use 5
- If the total weight equals or is less than 10, use 6
- If the total weight equals or is less than 30, use 5
- If the total weight is more than 30, use 0

The only that it doesn't work out (which is actually the first part of the formula):

- If the total weight equals 0, use 0

It keeps throwing 5 at me. Anyone has an idea what I'm getting wrong, and what this is called in the first place (having a hard time finding references on Google)?

Comment: Perhaps 0 is interpreted as false so the second `||` executes. And "0:0" isn't an operator.

Comment: `0` is falsy, and `something ? 0  : 0` always returns `0`, which is falsy, so it always moves to the right side of the logical OR.

Comment: It should also be noted that this makes no sense at all? The curlybraces makes no sense, the ternary statements makes no sense, the multiple checks of `total_weight` has no real logic to it, and makes no sense.

Comment: @adeneo: I have no technical background on this matter, so I can only rely on trial and error. The documentation on the module is less than poor, so I'm trying my luck here. The curly braces are tokens used by the module btw, so that would explain I guess.

Comment: How about just starting with simple `if ...  else` statements instead

Comment: This is the only documentation available btw: "Enter the calculation formula with components in brackets. 
Allowed operators: +, -, *, /, ^, (, ), %, ?, :, <, >, <=, >=, ==, &&, ||  
Example: {component1} + {component2} / {component3}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
({total_weight}==0? 0:0) || ({total_weight}<=2? 5:0) || ({total_weight}<=10? 6:0) || ({total_weight}<=30? 10.5:0)
```

If total_weight is 0 then it can be interpreted as:

```
(0 || ({total_weight}<=2? 5:0) || ({total_weight}<=10? 6:0) || ({total_weight}<=30? 10.5:0)
```

or

```
  (false || ({total_weight}<=2? 5:0) || ({total_weight}<=10? 6:0) || ({total_weight}<=30? 10.5:0)
```

Which causes the 2nd condition to execute. `0<=2` so the ternary "returns" 5

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there a way to fix this please? So that if a given number is 0, that it actually outputs 0?

Comment: Branch out the logic to if/else. And check ranges total_weight>2 && total_weight < 10

Comment: Since your reply is an answer to the actual question I'll mark it as such.

Comment: I'm using this now, and seems to to the job one way or another: {total_weight}<=0? 0:0 || {total_weight}<=2? 5:0 || {total_weight}<=10? 6:0 || {total_weight}<=2? 5:0 || {total_weight}<=30? 10.5:0

Comment: @cptstarling `(total_weight==0 ? 0:0 )|| (total_weight>=1 && total_weight<=10? 5:0) || (total_weight>=10 && total_weight<=30? 6:0) || (total_weight>=30? 10.5:0)`

Comment: You can adjust the ranges as you see fit